# Matrix Eigenvalue formula $|\lambda I-A |$ or $|A-\lambda I|$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

my lecturer wrote a solution for our exam, and he wrote the eigenvalue formula as $|\lambda I-A |$ instead of  $|A-\lambda I|$. What I understand is we use the latter to get the eigenvalue of a matrix.

Is this a typo or it doesn't matter whether it's $|A-\lambda I|$ or $|\lambda I-A |$?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That's the same equation, simply multiplied by $(-1)^n$, but solutions are just the same. It's like $$x+3=0$$ and $$-x-3=0$$ they are equivalent equations.

Comment: $|\lambda I - A| = |A- \lambda I|$.

Comment: okay thanks, just realized that

Comment: But if we have two 3x3 matrices, A & B, both have different values in their elements, the result of $|A-B|$ will not be the same as $|B-A|$ right? There's no such a thing as $|A-B|=|B-A|$, am I right?

Comment: @amWhy Not for odd-dimensional matrices. Those are determinants, not absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

Both are actually equivalent!

Let us recall how we derive the notion of eigenvalues and such. That is, for a square matrix $A$ and eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$, we have:

$$A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$$

Then,

$$A\vec{x} - \lambda \vec{x} = 0 \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; (A-\lambda I) \vec{x} = 0$$

Then we try to find $\lambda$ such that $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$.

But wait! We can do this a different way, as:

$$A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x} \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; 0 = \lambda \vec{x} - A \vec{x} \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; 0 = (\lambda I - A) \vec{x}$$

and thus we seek $\lambda$ such that $det(\lambda I - A) = 0$

Thus, as a result, you can use either equation - $det(\lambda I - A) = 0$ or $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$. Which you use is a matter of personal taste; I was actually taught the former but found the latter more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, then the polynomials $\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})$ and $\det(\lambda\operatorname{Id}-A)$ are equal if $n$ is even and symmetric otherwise. Therefore, they have the same zeros. So, as far as searching for eigenvalues is concerned, both provide the same information.

Comment: But if we have two 3x3 matrices, A & B, both have different values in their elements, the result of $|A−B|$ will not be the same as $|B−A|$ right? There's no such a thing as $|A−B|=|B−A|$, am I right?

Comment: They are no equal, but they are symmetric: if $C$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, $\det(-C)=-\det(C)$.

Comment: Technically, there is a property that is somewhat related. Note:

$$det(A-B) = det(-1 \cdot (B-A)) = (-1)^n det(B-A)$$

where $n$ is the size of the matrices (i.e. $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices). Notice what happens if $n$ is even. Generally, this property is stated for any scalar $k$:

$$det(kA) = k^n det(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

Just note that $\det (A-\lambda I) =(-1)^n\det (\lambda I-A)$, so $\lambda$ solves $ \det (A-\lambda I) =0$ if and only if it solves $\det (\lambda I-A)=0$, therefore you can calculate the eigenvalues of $A$ by solving $\det (\lambda I-A)=0$ or $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$. The solutions are the same.